# Jquery flip not displaying normal while using multiple cards

Tags: jquery, html, css, flip

I am using jquery flip library for flipping cards. 
i want to display the cards like this. 
[image: cards without flip lib]

but when i apply flip lib on more than one card than it displays like this,

[image: cards with flip lib]

the second flip card is under the third card. i am stuck on here what to do now. please help me to work normal.

here is my code.

> JQUERY

`$("#card1").flip({
    autoSize : true
});
$("#card2").flip({
    autoSize : true
});`

> HTML

```
<div class="project-item webdesign mobileapps photography" id="card1">
    <div class="front">
        <img src="include/images/portfolio-4.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <h4><a href="portfolio-single-1.html">Bold & Beautiful</a></h4>
        <p>
            Dow wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud at exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis exerci nisl. 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="project-item webdesign branding mobileapps photography" id="card2">
    <div class="project-image front">
        <img src="include/images/portfolio-2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <h4><a href="portfolio-single-1.html">Feeling Natural</a></h4>
        <p>
            Dow wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud at exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis exerci nisl. 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

i don't know where is the problem i am working it from 3 days. please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,

Hamaad

Answer (score 0):

It's a different approach but you can achieve a card-flipping effect, using just CSS.

**Working Example:**

```css
.card {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
margin: 12px;
border: 1px solid rgb(127,127,127);
cursor: pointer;
transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

.front, .back {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
font-size: 28px;
text-align: center;
}

.back {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
opacity: 0;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
transition: opacity 0s linear 0.25s;
}

.card:focus {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:focus .back {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" tabindex="0"> 
<div class="front">Front 1</div> 
<div class="back">Back 1</div> 
</div>

<div class="card" tabindex="0"> 
<div class="front">Front 2</div> 
<div class="back">Back 2</div> 
</div>

<div class="card" tabindex="0"> 
<div class="front">Front 3</div> 
<div class="back">Back 3</div> 
</div> 

<p>Click on each card to flip it.</p>
```